# If I use AGPL software (hosted on my environment) to populate DB data w/o any code changes, should I open the code of my software that does DB calls?

Tags: licensing, license, agpl-3.0

If I use AGPL service w/o code changes to populate data in the Mongo database and then retrieve this data from DB via my own-written service, should I open-source the code of my service? My own-written service is publicly available

Comment: is it part of something you're offering over the internet?

Comment: It will be WebAPI that I will use via REST API calls via main software

Comment: what is the main software?

Comment: Will be a Web service

Comment: so it seems like the question is whether your web service is a derivative work of this web API you are using

Comment: The main software will just access WebAPI via REST API calls, but does not use code of this WebAPI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you legally get data out of a GPL or AGPL program?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/12958/how-do-you-legally-get-data-out-of-a-gpl-or-agpl-program)

Comment: Does your service interact with or otherwise have knowledge of the AGPL service?

Comment: Interact via API calls